# What should a HTTP server do when clients use weak etags for subrange GET requests?

Tags: http, caching, etag

[RFC 2616 Section 13.3.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3):

> Clients MAY issue simple (non-subrange) GET requests with either weak
>   validators or strong validators. **Clients MUST NOT use weak validators
>   in other forms of request.**

Assuming all clients are RFC conforming, we will never see weak validators used for subrange GET requests.

However, since not all clients will be conforming, how should a HTTP server react when clients use weak validators for subrange GET requests?

Did the RFC have anything to say about this? Should the server inform the client of an error, or should it continue processing as though the validator does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the server. Both signalling an error or just returning the complete payload can make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "signalling a server"?

Comment: if we signal an error, what status code would be *correct* behavior?

Comment: 400, methinks (I don't think we have a more specific header field for that). That being said, I would just return the full payload.

Comment: do you mean you would have gave 200?